# Tem alguma forma de carregar Script ou CSS que se coloca no Buddles no ASP.NET somente em um única View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Geralmente quando baixo o plug-in no Visual Studio no NuGet, é necessário colocar script e css no Buddles entretanto estes scripts ficam carregando em todas as minhas Views mesmo as que não estão utilizando, portanto gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de colocar estes Scripts diretamente na View, pois sem colocar no Buddles no Visual studio, os plug-ins não funcionam.

Answer (score 0):

Tem sim.

As referências colocadas no BundleConfig não precisam necessariamente carregar em todas as páginas.
Você pode determinar em qual página deseja colocar o script da seguinte forma:

_Layout.cshtml

[image: _Layout.cshtml]

Edit.cshtml

[image: Edit.cshtml]

No exemplo acima, foram incluídas quatro referências no BundleConfig (jquery, bootstrap, jqueryval e jsTree).
No _Layout.cshtml estou utilizando somente as referências do jquery e bootstrap, e na página Edit estou utilizando as referências do jqueryval e do jstree.

Dessa forma, os scripts referenciados na página Edit só irão carregar ao entrar nela.